# Properties, Collections and Permissions information

Tags: marklogic

Where does properties, collection and permission information actually stored at? Is it included as part of each compressed document data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection and permissions information is stored in the universal index (ListIndex/ListData files on disk in the stand). The enumeration of collections is stored in a special range index if you enable the collections lexicon. Properties are stored in a separate fragment as part of the compressed tree data (TreeIndex/TreeData on disk).